# How to properly separate model validation from Controller into Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm in the middle of re-factoring the project I'm working on. In my existing controllers I do use the repository pattern, but I was still performing a little too much scaffolding than I felt comfortable with. That and some of my controllers could have 10+ repositories passed in (via Ninject). So, I decided to introduce a service layer where my intention is to have one service per controller and each service will instead have the multiple repositories injected into it and do the work I need. This works great so far, but I'm running into a confusion of sorts: How do I move the model validation away from the controller and into the service layer?

For example, take a look this `Edit` method on my `OfficesController`:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<RedirectToRouteResult> Edit(
    short id,
    FormCollection form,
    [Bind(Prefix = "Office.Coordinates", Include = "Latitude,Longitude")] Coordinate[] coordinates) {
    if (id > 0) {
        Office office = await this.OfficesService.GetOfficeAsync(id);

        if ((office != null)
            && base.TryUpdateModel(office, "Office", new string[2] {
                "Name",
                "RegionId"
            }, form)
            && base.ModelState.IsValid) {
            this.OfficesService.UpdateOfficeAsync(office, coordinates);
        }

        return base.RedirectToAction("Edit", new {
            id = id
        });
    }

    return base.RedirectToAction("Default");
}
```

The problem with it in comparison to the methods of the controller is that I still grab an `Office` object from the database, do the update, validate it, and then save it again. In this case the complexity increased rather than decrease. Before, I called the repository in the method, now I call the service which calls the repository to perform the same function. So far this increase in complexity has only show it self in my `Edit` methods, everywhere else the complexity decreased substantially, which is what I want.

So, what would be a proper way move validation, and now that I think about it, the model updating logic out of the controller and into the service? Recommendations are appreciated!

For reference, here's how my project is structured:

- **Data**: Contains all of my model classes
- **Data.Google.Maps**: Contains all classes I need to deserialize a specific Kml
- **Data.Models**: Contains my DbContext, configurations, view models and partial view models
- **Data.Repositories**: Contains all of my repositories that talk to the DbContext. Since EF is a pseudo repository on it's own, I'm leveraging my "repositories" as a more specific way of querying for data. For Example: `FindTechnicians()` or `FindActive()`, etc.
- **Data.Services**: Contains all of the services I will use. The services will have one or more repository injected into them and perform all of logic I need done before I pass a completed view model back to the controller.
- **Identity**: Contains my implementation of ASP.NET Identity.
- **Web.Private**: Contains the actual MVC project.

Comment: How many repository dependencies do your services have? Did you just move the dependency overinjection problem, or did yo solve it?

Comment: I just moved it to the service layer because I know I'll have to do some more complicated stuff with the results of some repositories and *then* pass the completed model into the controller.

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 articles you should read if you haven't already:

- https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91
- https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92

The answers to your problem are [FluentValidation.NET](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation) and dependency decoration.

With it, you could do something like this:

```
private readonly IExecuteCommands _commands;

[HttpPost]
public async Task<RedirectToRouteResult> Edit(short id, UpdateOffice command) {

    // with FV.NET plugged in, if your command validator fails,
    // ModelState will already be invalid
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(command);

    await _commands.Execute(command);
    return RedirectToAction(orWhateverYouDoAfterSuccess);
}
```

The command is just a plain DTO, like a viewmodel. Might look something like this:

```
public class UpdateOffice
{
    public int OfficeId { get; set; }
    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

... and the magic validator:

```
public class ValidateUpdateOfficeCommand : AbstractValidator<UpdateOffice>
{
    public ValidateUpdateOfficeCommand(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.OfficeId)
            .MustFindOfficeById(dbContext);

        RuleFor(x => x.RegionId)
            .MustFindRegionById(dbContext);

        RuleFor(x => x.Name)
            .NotEmpty()
            .Length(1, 200)
            .MustBeUniqueOfficeName(dbContext, x => x.OfficeId);
    }
}
```

Each of these validation rules will be run before your action method even gets executed, provided you have the validators set up for dependency injection and that you are using the FV MVC validation provider. If there is a validation error, ModelState.IsValid will be false.

You have also just solved the over injection problems in both your controller and (maybe) service layers. You can run any query, execute any command, or validate any object with only 3 interface dependencies.

Comment: I did read the first article earlier today, haven't read the second article, mostly because Steve's articles are rather lengthy. As far as the FluentValidation.NET you're referencing, how is it different than the EF Fluent API and is there still a benefit to it if I am using the EF Fluent API?

Comment: The EF fluent API is for mapping relational schema to conceptual object model, and its validations are minimal. You can make fields required and specify max length, but thats about it. With the above, your validator does the check to make sure all of your other business rules are not being broken. In SQL, you would have to do this with triggers, which EF has no fluent API for.